# Google.Apis.YouTube.v3 nuget package Sample Code & Port number

Tags: .net, api, youtube-api

I downloaded the sample project at: https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/dotnet , and using VS2013, is able to compile & run the project, but a browser windows opens (suspect it is the oath2 permissions window) complaining about an Error: redirect_uri_mismatch . From other Google searches I determined that it is because the port number changes every time I run the project and thus does not match the redirect uri set in the Google developers console. How would I go about getting the sample code to run?

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong type of credentials (Use Installed instead of web). Duh, feel so stupid now.